# Python reading data from different directories and merging into one excel file

Tags: pandas, error-handling, merge, concatenation, glob

I'm just a beginner in python. Now trying to use python for merging excel files from different directories.

I have a code as seen below. However when executed only one file is being read, and the other 2 files are not merged into the final excel file. Where should I make changed in the code?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Sincerely
Kerem

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os

#path = r'E:\Users\KEREMH\.spyder-py3\20210326GecikmedekiMusteriler'

subelistesi = ['1140','1150','1190']

klasor_adi= input('Klasör Adı: ')
gonderilen ='gonderilen'

for sube in subelistesi:

    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), sube, klasor_adi, gonderilen )

    filenames = glob.glob(path +  "/*.xlsx")
    
    print(filenames)

for file in filenames:

    concat_all_sheets_all_files = pd.DataFrame()

    df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None, skiprows=None,nrows=None,usecols=None,header=None,index_col=None)
    concat_all_sheets_single_file = pd.concat(df,sort=False)
    concat_all_sheets_single_file['filename']=os.path.basename(file)
    concat_all_sheets_all_files = concat_all_sheets_all_files.append(concat_all_sheets_single_file)
  
         
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'E:\Users\KEREMH\.spyder-py3\Konsolide.xlsx')
concat_all_sheets_all_files.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
print(concat_all_sheets_all_files)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you loop over `subelistesi`, only the last value of `filenames` is kept. A better way would be to create a list before any looping, and add all dataframes to it, then concat once finished looping.

```py
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os

#path = r'E:\Users\KEREMH\.spyder-py3\20210326GecikmedekiMusteriler'

subelistesi = ['1140','1150','1190']

klasor_adi= input('Klasör Adı: ')
gonderilen ='gonderilen'

all_dfs = [] # new list here

for sube in subelistesi:

    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), sube, klasor_adi, gonderilen )

    filenames = glob.glob(path +  "/*.xlsx")
    
    print(filenames)

    for file in filenames:

        concat_all_sheets_all_files = pd.DataFrame()

        df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None, skiprows=None,nrows=None,usecols=None,header=None,index_col=None)
        df['filename'] = os.path.basename(file)
        all_dfs.append(df)
        

concat_all_sheets_all_files = pd.concat(all_dfs, axis=0)

         
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'E:\Users\KEREMH\.spyder-py3\Konsolide.xlsx')
concat_all_sheets_all_files.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
print(concat_all_sheets_all_files)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, appreciate it